# Importing stored connections from Mysql Gui tools to Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, connection, mysql-workbench, mysql-gui-tools

I've been working with Mysql Gui tools (for 5.0) at work for nearly 2 years and have accumulated about 100 stored connections.
We're now upgrading to use Mysql Workbench 5.3 Community Edition and i'm looking for a way to import, convert or any other way to make my stored connections available in Workbench.

I've looked around for ways to do this but found very little, even no topics or threads on how to go about this.

Only thing i've found is someone stating that the xml used to store the connections for both apps is completely different and non-trivial to convert by hand.

Does anyone know of a tool, plugin or method to get the stored connections from the gui tools into Workbench?

By Gui tools i mean the seperate programs Query Browser, Administrator and System tray monitor.